# Write a function named first_word that returns the first word in a string

Tags: python, string, function, return

My buddy sent me a screenshot a question he was stuck on for an assessment and asked if I was able to help. So I took a shot at it and it's been two days now and this is haunting my dreams.

Question: "create a function named first_word that takes in a string and returns the first word.

Given Code:

```
assert first_word("Random string here") == "Random"
assert first_word("Another random string here") == "Another"
assert first_word("Again a random string... etc.") == "Again"
print("Excerscise is complete"
```

What I have Tried amongst other variations:

```
def first_word(x):
        print(first_word.split().pop(0))
        return first_word
assert first_word("Random string here") == "Random"
assert first_word("Another random string here") == "Another"
assert first_word("Again a random string... etc.") == "Again"
print("Excerscise is complete"



def first_word(x):
        print(first_word.split()
        return
assert first_word("Random string here") == "Random"
assert first_word("Another random string here") == "Another"
assert first_word("Again a random string... etc.") == "Again"
print("Excerscise is complete"
```

I have tried a lot of different combinations and can't think to add them all, I have looked up online and I can't seem to make the code work how it was for the assessment. I can return the first letter but I cannot wrap my brain around how to get the first word.

This assessment my friend is doing has no actual impact on me, and it's already passed so he will gain nothing from this. I merely want to understand how to complete this task that will help me figure out why it is failing.

I currently work in eDiscovery and am working towards getting my security + and OSCP. I feel gaining any knowledge of python will be beneficial. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

-Oerml

Comment: I realize that I have left off the closing parenthesis following the closing print statement. This was a typo, and not an error that I am encountering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right basic idea here:

```
def first_word(x):
    print(first_word.split().pop(0))
    return first_word
```

but are confused about the syntax:

- `first_word` is the *function*, and `x` is the string *parameter* that you're trying to get the first word of.  `first_word.split()` doesn't make sense, because you can't `split()` a function.  What you *can* `split()` is `x`.
- You're mixing up `print` and `return`.  Your function is supposed to `return` the first word (not `first_word`, which is the function itself, but the string you get by splitting `x`), and not `print` it.

This should work:

```
def first_word(x):
    return x.split()[0]
```

Comment: I'll suggest also that rather than randomly trying combinations of words trying to get something to work (which is going to just lead to you bashing your head against walls forever), you should go through a Python tutorial and actually learn the language step by step.  It feels like more work, but it's really not.